Why is My Pointer Being Overwritten Outside This Loop?
I am writing the implementation of a binary scene file reader in C. I have come to the decoding step, and it seems my pointers are being corrupted. The problem is not the decoder, the information I need is being decoded flawlessly, it's with the linked list I use to store scene/texture data.
The scene and linked list structures looks like this;
typedef enum NodeType
{
    shader,
    texture,
    instance,
    scene
} NodeType;

typedef union NodeContents
{
    Shader* shader;
    Texture* texture;
    TextureInstance* instance;
    Scene* scene;
} NodeContents;

typedef struct Node
{
    struct Node* next;
    const char* name;
    NodeType type;

    NodeContents contents;
} Node;

typedef struct LinkedList
{
    NodeType type;

    Node* first_node;
    Node* last_node;
} LinkedList;

typedef struct Scene
{
    LinkedList* scene_contents; // Texture array
    char name[32], description[64];
} Scene;

As for important helper functions:
// Note that this is not all in one file, it is a collection of various utilities.

#define __MALLOC(type, allocated, error_message)                     \
    malloc(sizeof(type));                                            \
    if (allocated == NULL) (PrintError error_message)

Texture* CreateTextureFromMemory(const char* name, u8* image, u64 image_size,
                        TextureType type, f32 window_width,
                        f32 window_height)
{
    Texture* texture =
        __MALLOC(Texture, texture,
                 ("Failed to allocate the texture '%s'. Code: %d.",
                  name, errno));

    _InitializeOpenGLTexture(&texture->texture, GL_CLAMP_TO_BORDER,
                             GL_NEAREST_MIPMAP_NEAREST, GL_NEAREST);

    i32 image_width, image_height, image_channels;
    u8* image_content =
        stbi_load_from_memory(image, image_size, &image_width,
                              &image_height, &image_channels, 0);

    if (image_channels == 3) glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
    else glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 4);

    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0,
                 (image_channels == 3 ? GL_RGB : GL_RGBA),
                 image_width, image_height, 0,
                 (image_channels == 3 ? GL_RGB : GL_RGBA),
                 GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image_content);
    glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    stbi_image_free(image_content);

    _InsertTextureData(texture, name, window_width / image_width,
                       window_height / image_height);

    texture->vao =
        _GenerateVertexBuffer(texture->width, texture->height);

    PrintSuccess("Loaded texture '%s' from memory.", name);
    return texture;
}

#define __TYPE_SWITCH(type, ex1, ex2, ex3, ex4)                      \
    switch (type)                                                    \
    {                                                                \
        case shader:   ex1; break;                                   \
        case texture:  ex2; break;                                   \
        case instance: ex3; break;                                   \
        case scene:    ex4; break;                                      \
    }

Node* __CreateNode(NodeType type, const char* name, void* contents)
{
    Node* created_node = __MALLOC(
        Node, created_node,
        ("Failed to allocate node '%s'. Code: %d.", name, errno));
    created_node->next = NULL;
    created_node->name = name;
    created_node->type = type;

    __TYPE_SWITCH(type, created_node->contents.shader = contents,
                  created_node->contents.texture = contents,
                  created_node->contents.instance = contents,
                  created_node->contents.scene = contents);

    return created_node;
}

LinkedList* CreateLinkedList(Node* head)
{
    LinkedList* created_list = __MALLOC(
        LinkedList, created_list,
        ("Failed to allocate node list of type %d. Code: %d.",
         head->type, errno));
    created_list->type = head->type;
    created_list->first_node = head;
    created_list->last_node = head;

    return created_list;
}

void AppendNode(LinkedList* list, Node* node)
{
    (list)->last_node->next = node;
    (list)->last_node = (list)->last_node->next;
}

And the full decoder is as follows;
#define __READ_STRING(buffer, length, file)                          \
    ReadFromFile(buffer, length, 1, file);                           \
    buffer[length] = '\0'

__INLINE void ReadFromFile(void* restrict ptr, u32 size, u32 number,
                           FILE* stream)
{
    u32 written_size = fread(ptr, size, number, stream);
    if (written_size != number && feof(stream) != 0)
    {
        PrintError("The read call to the scene file hit the end of "
                   "the file. The scene file is malformed/damaged.");
    }
    else if (written_size != number)
        PrintError("The read call to the scene file hit an error.");
}

LinkedList* LoadScenes(f32 window_width, f32 window_height)
{
    LinkedList* loaded_scenes = NULL;

    FILE* scene_file = fopen("./Assets/scenes.resource", "rb");
    if (scene_file == NULL)
        PrintError("Renai seems to not have a scene file.");

    u8 header_beginning[2];
    ReadFromFile(header_beginning, 1, 2, scene_file);
    if (header_beginning[0] != 0xFF || header_beginning[1] != 0x01)
        PrintError("Loaded scene file has been tampered with/is "
                   "malformed. Unable to continue.");

    u8 version[3];
    ReadFromFile(version, 1, 3, scene_file);
    CheckVersionDifference("scenes", version);

    u16 scene_count;
    ReadFromFile(&scene_count, 2, 1, scene_file);

    u8 header_end[2];
    ReadFromFile(header_end, 1, 2, scene_file);
    if (header_end[0] != 0xFF || header_end[1] != 0x02)
        PrintError("Loaded scene file has been tampered with/is "
                   "malformed. Unable to continue.");

    for (u16 scene_index = 0; scene_index < scene_count;
         scene_index++)
    {
        Scene* current_scene =
            __MALLOC(Scene, current_scene,
                     ("Failed to allocate space for a scene."));
        current_scene->scene_contents = NULL;

        u16 scene_data_lengths[3];
        ReadFromFile(scene_data_lengths, 2, 3, scene_file);

        __READ_STRING(current_scene->name, scene_data_lengths[0],
                      scene_file);
        __READ_STRING(current_scene->description,
                      scene_data_lengths[1], scene_file);

        for (u16 texture_list_index = 0;
             texture_list_index < scene_data_lengths[2];
             texture_list_index++)
        {
            u8 file_name_length;
            ReadFromFile(&file_name_length, 1, 1, scene_file);

            char file_name[file_name_length];
            __READ_STRING(file_name, file_name_length, scene_file);

            u64 image_size;
            ReadFromFile(&image_size, 8, 1, scene_file);
            u8 image[image_size];
            ReadFromFile(image, 1, image_size, scene_file);

            Texture* loaded_texture = CreateTextureFromMemory(
                file_name, image, image_size, tileset, window_width,
                window_height);

            if (current_scene->scene_contents == NULL)
                current_scene->scene_contents = CreateLinkedList(
                    __CreateNode(texture, file_name, loaded_texture));
            else
                AppendNode(
                    current_scene->scene_contents,
                    __CreateNode(texture, file_name, loaded_texture));

            printf("\n\n%s\n",
                   current_scene->scene_contents->first_node->name);
        }
        printf("\n\n%s\n",
               current_scene->scene_contents->first_node->name);

        if (loaded_scenes == NULL)
            loaded_scenes = CreateLinkedList(__CreateNode(
                scene, current_scene->name, current_scene));
        else
            AppendNode(loaded_scenes,
                       __CreateNode(scene, current_scene->name,
                                    current_scene));
    }

    fclose(scene_file);
    return loaded_scenes;
}

I get the name and description properties of the scene perfectly. Within the texture loop, I get everything perfectly, but as soon as I step outside the loop, the current_scene->scene_contents object begins to be corrupted. Does anyone have any idea why this is? Also, please ignore any problems that don't explicitly pertain to the question; this is not production code, and much of it is awful.
If anything needs clarifying or expanding upon, do not hesitate to ask.
Edit: I have added needed helper function/macro definitions that were missing in the original post.

If you're 100% sure that those other functions work correctly, then you may want to create a [mre], without those. There's a lot of code here, almost all of which uses functions we don't have access to.

@Zenais, Why no fclose()?

Also, why is __READ_STRING a macro and not a function? And - more important - why does it not check the return of fread to see how much was actually read?

Names that being with two underscores are reserved identifiers per the C standard and your use of them invokes undefined behavior.  A symbol such as __MALLOC seems highly likely to create a name collision.

@AndrewHenle I did not know that, thank you. I always assumed that it was a single underscore, noting _Noreturn and _Alignof. I will change that in my program.

@chux-ReinstateMonica It is in the actual program, not entirely certain why I didn't copy it over here. Thank you for catching that.

@ThomasJager That is a good point. I will amend the question to add those details.

@BoP I did not see a reason to make it a function, as it was only two statements. Do you truly believe it deserves to be one?

@Zenais CheckVersionDifference("scenes", version); is suspicious. Does that function assume version points to a string, which is isn't, or a character array of 3?

@Zenais Why does code not check the return values of fread() before using the data read into the buffers?

@chux-ReinstateMonica That function was very minor, so I didn't think it mattered, but I can see why it may be suspicious. The first parameter (defined in my code as reason) is what the error reporter will output as the reason for failure if the version of the program and scene file do not match closely enough. The second parameter is simply an array of three bytes, each checked individually by a series of conditionals.

@chux-ReinstateMonica I was hacking this together very quickly, and my workflow tends to insert error checking towards the tail end of component development. I simply assume it does, for the sake of simplicity. That, unfortunately, is not the problem here, as all data enters the buffers perfectly while inside the loop, but quickly become garbled outside of it.

@Zenais "code not check the return values of fread()"_ and "is not the problem here", yet code does have some trouble - sounds a bit like Pay no attention to that man behind the curtain..  Even if not the issue, demoing robust code checks helps us all focus on the real issues.  Your call.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Have you run it through ASAN, UBSAN and valgrind?  Switched on all compiler warnings?

Apart from the problem you are asking about, this code could really do with a code review, since there are multiple forms of very bad practices here. When you got it working, consider posting the working code at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

@Lundin Noted, thank you.
